# Are there any major advantages of moving Java development of a server-based product to 64-bit?

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

Currently, all development compiles in 32-bit Java. We are going to move all development to the latest version of Eclipse, and so we are thinking if this may be a good opportunity to also move all development to 64-bit. The product is heavily using servers (Tomcat) and databases, and so there is a clear advantage for performance enhancements here. But beyond this, are there any other advantages? It also comes with more overhead as well.

Also, how much effort is required to move development to 64-bit? I know for C, it's only really little coding and LP64 is the best solution, but I'm unable to find anything in regards to Java.

Cheers.

Comment: Java byte code is neither 32 or 64 bit, the only thing that makes that difference is the implementation of the jvm. The major difference between the two is the amount of addressable memory available to the JVM...

Answer (score 2):

One of the major advantages of developing in Java is that you can develop on any supported platform, and - if you avoid known platform specific things - deploy to any supported platform.

In this regard 32-bit and 64-bit are two separate platforms.

If you do not hit the 32-bit memory limit for your environment, you will utilize existing resource best with a 32-bit JVM even on 64-bit systems.

Remember that your test environments (including CI engine) should be exactly the same as you use in production.